# what are the instructions for compiling in IBM Jikes

Tags: java, compilation

what is the instruction for compiling via IBM Jikes .

for example :

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you read the [Jikes](http://jikes.sourceforge.net/faq/user-index.shtml#usage) FAQ, you will see how to use it. The invocation is basically identical to `javac`